# Django & Maps Return the Area

Tags: python, django, google-maps, gis

I would like to create an Airbnb alike website but not for houses. I will have an embedded Google (or something else) Maps and when user types an area, Django will search on the database and brings the available data for that specific area. If you can at least give me an idea where to start, I would appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in your DB, should has nothing to do with map. You usually input a location and find the entries within the distance, which is calculate somehow; or you put in a zip code, or city name, and find the entries within the city or have same zip code. Then you populate it on to the map for user to see.

So when user enter a name, or address, you probably should use the [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to translate it into coordinates or zip code too.

hope this help you get started.